# How to properly format queries while inserting Commas to Separate Strings in SQLITE

Tags: android, sqlite, syntax

I need to insert coordinates in SQLLIte Table in Android

My Query is as below .
Its gives a Syntax error due to cordinates which contain string by comma separated information .

```
INSERT INTO "tableNonOilFarmer" ("farmerId","FirstName","MiddleName","LastName","FatherName","DOB","CategoryId","MobileNo","LandlineNo","StateId","DistrictId","TalukaMandalId","ClusterId","VillageId","Pincode","RsNumber","Area","LocationId","BorewellAvailable","BorewellDepth","SoilType","Flood","CurrentCropId","CurrentCropStatusId","CurrentCropAge","CurrentCropRating","Awareness","Interested","ContactDate","NextCrop","OverallRating","CreatedOn","Latitude","Longitude","Coordinates","Converted","Status","StatusBy","StatusDate","Comments","UserId","Sync") VALUES (3,test,test,test,test,2017-12-27,6,64,58,1,01,02,01,04,96559,1,1,1,false,353,kdf,1,1,1,5555,3,true,true,2017-12-27,,5,2017-12-27,16.868542,81.306554,81.30682,16.8682,0 81.306309,16.86842,0 81.306607,16.869098,0 81.307039,16.868813,0 81.30682,16.8682,0,false,0,null,1,null,167,S)
```

Comment: I can see an extra comma in your query just after the date

Comment: There are multiple syntax issues there. Consider using variable binding instead of raw string values - for example `ContentValues`.

Comment: I tried with Content Values , it gave -1

Comment: @Yatin I think My Answer may help you to mange inserting data with Commas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can Use PreparedStatement for inserting the Data with commas

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO tableNonOilFarmer (FirstName,Adress) VALUES (?,?)");
stmt.bindString(1, "First");
stmt.bindString(2, "No 1, 1st street, MyCity");
stmt.execute();
```